# Django : ValueError at / The 'avatar' attribute has no file associated with it

Tags: django, attributes, valueerror

Django sends me the following error:
ValueError at /
The 'avatar' attribute has no file associated with it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZQoC.png)

The message appears just after I log in, even though I uploaded an avatar when I registered a dummy profile.

I can't even find the avatar in the configured path: media/avatars.

Could you help find where I got this wrong please?
Bellow is my code.

**models.py:
**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    (some code)
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/',blank=True, null=True)
```

**forms.py:
**

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    (some code)

    avatar = forms.ImageField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control"
            }
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','first_name','last_name','email','avatar','password1','password2','user_type']
```

**settings.py:
**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'media'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
```

I added this in **urls.py** of the main project directory:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And finally, the path of where I want the avatars to be uploaded:

mainProject
├── media
│   ├── avatars

Thank you very much for any help

I tried to make all the uploaded avatars go to media/avatars.

I even made conditions where there is a placeholder image in case the user doesn't upload any avatar:

```
          {% if user.avatar %}
            <img src="{{ user.avatar.url }}">
          {% else %}
            <img src="{% static 'images/cat.png' %}">
          {% endif %}
```

There is indeed a 'cat.png' image in static/images/

Comment: Try `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` and then restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

hope you haven't forgotton to apply makemigration and migrate! do you have github repo of it, i want to have a through look at before commenting.

Comment: Hi! I don't have github repo but I will share my work soon! I did makemigrations and migrate but it still didn't work...

Comment: I see. in the error image that you shared, it is still 
<img src="{{user.avatar.url}}" class="rounded-circle" with="50"> 
instead of           
{% if user.avatar %}
      <img src="{{ user.avatar.url }}">
  {% else %}
       <img src="{% static 'images/cat.png' %}">
 {% endif %}. So may be restarting server or clearing cache will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
#settings.py
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static’)
MEDIA_ROOT =os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I actually imported Path from pathlib instead of os

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**